# Bresenham's algorithm in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, mingw, glut, bresenham

This is my fist time studying Computer Graphics and i was given the code below from my professor. I think i have understood how the algorithm is implemented in general, but what i fail to understand is in what way the `incx,incy,inc1,inc2` lines work. I obviously know they are there to increase something but since i haven't fully understood the algorithm i'm kinda baffled. This is the full code:

```c
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int xstart, ystart, xend, yend;

void myInit() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 500, 0, 500);
}

void draw_pixel(int x, int y) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
}

void draw_line(int xstart, int xend, int ystart, int yend) {
    int dx, dy, i, e;
    int incx, incy, inc1, inc2;
    int x,y;

    dx = xend-xstart;
    dy = yend-ystart;

    if (dx < 0) dx = -dx;
    if (dy < 0) dy = -dy;
    incx = 1;
    if (xend < xstart) incx = -1;
    incy = 1;
    if (yend < ystart) incy = -1;
    x = xstart;
    y = ystart;
    if (dx > dy) {
        draw_pixel(x, y);
        e = 2 * dy-dx;
        inc1 = 2*(dy-dx);
        inc2 = 2*dy;
        for (i=0; i<dx; i++) {
            if (e >= 0) {
                y += incy;
                e += inc1;
            }
            else
                e += inc2;
            x += incx;
            draw_pixel(x, y);
        }

    } else {
        draw_pixel(x, y);
        e = 2*dx-dy;
        inc1 = 2*(dx-dy);
        inc2 = 2*dx;
        for (i=0; i<dy; i++) {
            if (e >= 0) {
                x += incx;
                e += inc1;
            }
            else
                e += inc2;
            y += incy;
            draw_pixel(x, y);
        }
    }
}

void myDisplay() {
    draw_line(xstart, xend, ystart, yend);
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf( "Enter (xstart, ystart, xend, yend)\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &xstart, &ystart, &xend, &yend);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Bresenham's Line Algorithm Visualization");
    myInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: So you're essentially asking how does Bresenham's algorithm work. While someone may post an explanation here, you can just as well go and read plenty of other explanations available online. [\[1\]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)[\[2\]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-line-generation-algorithm/)[\[3\]](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html)

Comment: The year is 2020, OpenGL 4.6, Vulkan....And you're stuck with glBegin()...

Comment: @MichaelIV - which is fine for high performance graphics, as long as the poster wants to spend more time than his/her project allows with lots of copy / paste just for the GFX equivalent of 'hello world'. It's a pity there's no simple mode 0x13 access anymore - ideal for learning raster algorithms.

Comment: This isn't a well-posed question. Your professor has given you a starting point, not a complete solution. Traditionally, you would ensure that your code can handle all 8 'octants' (this will make sense when you read classic descriptions of the algorithm) - and when it's working for all endpoints, you can start factoring out common code. OTOH, there's [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#C), which can probably directly replace your 'draw_line' function.